# input tabular suggestions js

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I was stuck on getting things working for input tabular suggestions. The problem is that I want to create the input field inside the controller. I found [this example](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3811696), but it is using the XML view for creating the field.

I tried to convert the example to JS, but I really had a lot of errors starting with suggestion rows and columns. How should I implement this? This is what I have tried:

```js
new sap.m.Input({
    visible: "{= ${UserId} === '' ? true : false}",
    /*  showValueHelp="true",*/
    showSuggestion: true,
    valueHelpRequest: "onManageServiceOwners",
    suggest: "handleInputSuggest",
    /* suggestionRows: "{ path: 'serviceDetailsModel>/SuggestedServiceOwners' }",*/
    suggestionRows: sap.m.input.insertSuggestionRow(item, -1) ,
    suggestionColumns: sap.m.input.insertSuggestionColumn(oSuggestionColumn,  -1),
    submit: (this.onSubmitOwnerId).bind(this)
})
```

Comment: you could use "bindSuggestionColumns" and "bindSuggestionRows" functionality on your input control

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I have edited your question to improve formatting and wording and make it slightly clearer. You can find out more about how to use the S.O. markdown [on the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Once you get an answer that solves your problem, please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to help any further users which have a similar issue and to reward the user which answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside an XML View, you have it [in the SDK samples](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputAssistedTabularSuggestions/code).

Using JS + XML view you can find here [a working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/57U0pP1lVTa71V69N4bC?p=preview) and the snippet:

```js
var oInput = new sap.m.Input({
    showSuggestion: true,
    showTableSuggestionValueHelp: false,
    suggestionColumns: [
        new sap.m.Column({
            label: new sap.m.Label({ text: "Name" })
        }),
        new sap.m.Column({
            label: new sap.m.Label({ text: "ProductId" })
        }),
        new sap.m.Column({
            label: new sap.m.Label({ text: "SupplierName" })
        })
    ],
    suggestionRows: {
        path: "/ProductCollection",
        template: new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
            cells: [
                new sap.m.Text({
                    text: { path: "Name" }
                }),
                new sap.m.Text({
                    text: { path: "ProductId" }
                }),
                new sap.m.Text({
                    text: { path: "SupplierName" }
                })
            ]
        })
    },
});
```